# Returning a display from a Corona OOP class

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am new to Corona and am trying to get some basic OOP going on.  I have an application which requires a number of time picker widgets, and would like to be able to reuse a 'timepicker' class for each instance.  Here's my code so far (bare bones - timepicker.lua):

```
module(..., package.seeall)

local widget = require "widget"

picker = {}
picker.__index = picker

function picker.new()
    local picker_object = {}
    setmetatable(picker_object,picker)

    pickerGroup = display.newGroup()

    picker_object.theHour = 0
    picker_object.theMin = 0
    picker_object.am = true

    picker_object.increaseHrBtn = widget.newButton{
        default="gfx/up_regular.png",
        over="gfx/up_press.png",
        width=40, height=40,
        onRelease = picker.incHr
    }

    picker_object.decreaseHrBtn = widget.newButton{
        default="gfx/down_regular.png",
        over="gfx/down_press.png",
        width=40, height=40,
        onRelease = picker.decHr
    }

    picker_object.decreaseHrBtn.y = 100

    pickerGroup:insert(picker_object.increaseHrBtn.view)
    pickerGroup:insert(picker_object.decreaseHrBtn.view)

    return picker_object
end

function picker:incHr(event)
    print("inc")
end

function picker:decHr(event)
    print("dec")
end
```

and here is where I instantiate it:

```
local TimePicker = require("timepicker")
local reminderPicker1 = TimePicker.picker.new()
```

This gives me a functioning time picker on the screen (or the first two buttons of which, anyhow).  But I want to grab the display objects of this picker and put them into my scroll view on the screen.  Because the class returns an object, this can't be inserted into the scroll view.  I'm sure it's a basic thing, but I can't figure out what I need to do next!  Can anyone help?  Much appreciated.

EDIT

Posting my class, which seems to be almost there, except am having trouble accessing the variables 'theHour' and 'theMin' from within the class...

```
module(..., package.seeall)

local widget = require "widget"

picker = {}
picker.__index = picker

function picker.new()
    local picker_object = {}
    setmetatable(picker_object,picker)

    picker_object.theHour = 12
    picker_object.theMin = 0
    picker_object.am = true

    picker_object.increaseHrBtn = widget.newButton{
        default="gfx/up_regular.png",
        over="gfx/up_press.png",
        width=40, height=40,
        onRelease = picker.incHr
    }

    picker_object.decreaseHrBtn = widget.newButton{
        default="gfx/down_regular.png",
        over="gfx/down_press.png",
        width=40, height=40,
        onRelease = picker.decHr
    }

    picker_object.decreaseHrBtn.y = 100

    picker_object.hrText = display.newText("12", 6, 41, native.systemFont, 24)
    picker_object.hrText:setTextColor(0, 0, 0)

    picker_object.dotsText = display.newText(":", 58, 39, native.systemFont, 24)
    picker_object.dotsText:setTextColor(0, 0, 0)

    picker_object.increaseMinBtn = widget.newButton{
        default="gfx/up_regular.png",
        over="gfx/up_press.png",
        width=40, height=40,
        onRelease = picker.incMin
    }

    picker_object.increaseMinBtn.x = 100

    picker_object.decreaseMinBtn = widget.newButton{
        default="gfx/down_regular.png",
        over="gfx/down_press.png",
        width=40, height=40,
        onRelease = picker.decMin
    }
    picker_object.decreaseMinBtn.y = 100
    picker_object.decreaseMinBtn.x = 100

    picker_object.minText = display.newText("00", 86, 41, native.systemFont, 24)
    picker_object.minText:setTextColor(0, 0, 0)

    picker_object.ampmBtn = widget.newButton{
        default="gfx/blank_normal.png",
        over="gfx/blank_press.png",
        label = "AM",
        font = "Korean Calligraphy",
        fontSize = 25,
        width=58, height=58,
        onRelease = picker.toggleAmPm
    }

    picker_object.ampmBtn.x = 160
    picker_object.ampmBtn.y = 58

    return picker_object
end

function picker:getHour()
    return self.theHour
end

function picker:getMin()
    return self.theMin
end

function picker:incHr(event)
    print("inc")
    if self.theHour < 12 then
        self.theHour = self.theHour + 1
    else 
        self.theHour = 1
    end

    if self.theHour < 10 then
        picker_object.hrText.text = "0"..self.theHour
    else
        picker_object.hrText.text = self.theHour
    end
end

function picker:decHr(event)
    print("dec")
    if self.theHour > 1 then
        self.theHour = self.theHour - 1
    else 
        self.theHour = 12
    end
    if self.theHour < 10 then
        picker_object.hrText.text = "0"..self.theHour
    else
        picker_object.hrText.text = self.theHour
    end
end

function picker:incMin(event)
    print("inc")
    if self.theMin < 59 then
        self.theMin = self.theMin + 1
    else 
        self.theMin = 0
    end

    if self.theMin < 10 then
        picker_object.minText.text = "0"..self.theMin
    else
        self.minText.text = self.theMin
    end
end

function picker:decMin(event)
    print("dec")
    if self.theMin > 0 then
        self.theMin = self.theMin - 1
    else 
        self.theMin = 59
    end
    if self.theMin < 10 then
        picker_object.minText.text = "0"..self.theMin
    else
        picker_object.minText.text = self.theMin
    end
end

function picker:toggleAmPm(event)
    if self.am == true then
        self.am = false
        picker_object.ampmBtn:setLabel( "PM" )
    else
        self.am = true
        picker_object.ampmBtn:setLabel( "AM" )
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! you had asked in your previous question right. I forgot to answer that.

Anyway you can access the display objects as 
`reminderPicker1.increaseHrBtn`,`reminderPicker1.decreaseHrBtn` and so on.

Inside class methods you can access them as 
`self.increaseHrBtn`, `self.decreaseHrBtn`

**EDIT**

Change `onRelease = picker.toggleAmPm` to

```
onRelease = function() picker_object:toggleAmPm() end
```

And change `picker_object.ampmBtn:setLabel( "PM" )`to

```
self.ampmBtn:setLabel( "PM" )
```

DO the same for all other instances. And you'll be fine!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Satheesh!  Going to try the code out tonight :)

Comment: oh no, error: bad argument #-2 to 'insert' (Proxy expected, got nil), when trying to do the following: scrollView:insert(reminderPicker1.increaseHrBtn)

Comment: oh excuse me, forgot the all important increaseHrBtn.view, because it's a widget :)  it works!  thank you!

Comment: argh, but after all that, I've put in two time pickers and again, the controls of the first one affect the properties of the second one!  I must have messed up the OOP again!  Can you see any errors in the code I posted above? :(

Comment: How exactly do the `the controls of the first one affect the properties of the second one` ?

Comment: I realised that I had removed the 'local' from the picker_object and that was what was making the pickers share the variables.  but when i make the picker_object local, I can't seem to access the 'theHour' variable from within my functions.  Is 'picker_object.theHour = 0' the correct way to define them?  Using self.picker_object doesn't find them either...

Comment: Updating my question with my latest code.  I can use the functions getHr and getMin from outside the class no problem, but the functions attached to the buttons within the class, which are trying to reference values using 'self' are throwing the error that the variables theHr and theMin are nil...

Comment: I meant 'theHour', not 'theHr'

Comment: Oh my.  Still problems I'm afraid.  I changed the code as per your suggestion, and got the following error when I clicked a button: 'attempt to index global 'picker_object' (a nil value)' - I tried changing the picker_object to picker, like this: 'onRelease = function() picker:toggleAmPm() end' - but then I get 'attempt to compare nil with number' - suggesting the self.theHour value is nil.  Any ideas?

Comment: After all this, the solution was to put the incHr etc functions INSIDE the picker.new() function, and define them thus: function picker_object:incHr